# segmentation fault in simpe c++ code

Tags: c++, linux

i'm using code::bocks on GNU/linux/
I know what is segmentation fault, just curious what caused it in this case.
why doest it return segmentation fault:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int tab1[3];
        tab1[0] = 2 + 7 * 16 - 8;
        tab1[1] = 22 * 2 / 11;
        tab1[2] = 8383 - 222 + 292 * 8;
        tab1[3] = 5 * 2 * 4;

    cout << " " << tab1[1];
    return 0;
}
```

and this not

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int tab1[3];
        tab1[0] = 2 + 7 * 16 - 8;
        tab1[1] = 22 * 2 / 11;
        tab1[2] = 8383 - 222 + 292 * 8;
        tab1[3] = 5 * 2 * 4;

    cout << tab1[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int tab1[3]` declares elements 0 through 2 inclusive.  But you used 0 through 3.  So both version of your program are broken.  But sometimes undefined behavior has no visible symptom.  So neither getting a seg fault nor not getting a seg fault should be surprising.

Comment: When you overwrite an array you get undefined behaviour. Basically the symptoms depend on what in memory you are attempting to overwrite.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3, where's the last one gonna be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to assign to `tab1[3]` which is outside of the array bounds. This is undefined behaviour and causing your segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the array tab1 to have space for 3 elements, but in the code you assign values to four elementes. `tab1[3] = 5 * 2 * 4;` writes to memory outside the array.  It's probably just a coincidence that one program segfaults while the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the array with an index that's out-of-bounds.

```
int tab1[3];
tab1[0] = 2 + 7 * 16 - 8;
tab1[1] = 22 * 2 / 11;
tab1[2] = 8383 - 222 + 292 * 8;
tab1[3] = 5 * 2 * 4;  // <-- Error
```

Arrays start from index `0`, and go up to `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of items in the array.  Thus the largest index is `2` for an array with `3` items in it.

Now why the different behavior?  Accessing an array out-of-bounds is *undefined behavior*.  You cannot reliably predict what will happen when errors such as an out-of-bounds access occurs.